# Dissociate Elastic IP in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I was checking through terraform documentation for two things which i could not find.

1. Disassociating an elastic IP from an existing EC2 so that it can be assigned to a newer instance.
2. Getting the EC2 instance attachment information from EBS volume id.

Please let me know if the above two features exist in terraform or there are alternative ways to get the above information. Can such features be requested to be added to terraform anywhere.

Comment: what do you mean by `etting the EC2 instance attachment information the its volume id.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Disassociating an elastic IP from an existing EC2 so that it can be assigned to a newer instance.

To create association you have to use [aws_eip_association](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eip_association). Subsequently, to delete the association, you remove `aws_eip_association` from your TF code.

> Getting the EC2 instance attachment information the its volume id.

Its not supported. You can develop your own [external data source](https://www.cloudwalker.io/2021/10/09/terraform-external-data-source/) to get any information you want and which is not directly supported by TF.

> Can such features be requested to be added to terraform anywhere.

Yes, you can make `Issues` on github: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws

Comment: Regarding the dissociation of elastic IP, i want to attach the elastic_ip from an existing instance to a newer instance that will be launched via terraform. So i can not remove the aws_eip_association part which does not exist. Hence i wanted to disassociate the ip from the existing instance.

Comment: @RaviKumarCH I would suggest making new question with your TF code and any errors you get. Otherwise, only a generic answer as I did can be given to your very generic question.